# leftcalloutaccessoryView takes the whole annotation View

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I want to display a Photo inside the leftaccessoryview
just like below Image
[image: Like this]

But I tried to set the image from the photo library the image takes the full annotationView and I didn't see the title at all
Here is the code I've used

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {


if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
   return nil;

static NSString *AnnotationIdentifier=@"AnnotationIdentifier";
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc ]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

UIButton *rbutton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rbutton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[rbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=rbutton;
if (image) {
    UIImageView *temp=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];


    pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView=temp;
}


return pinView;
```

}

`image` is a `UIImage` where i am storing the image picked from image picker.
I'm getting this as output.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use :

```
temp.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

or try :

```
UIView *viewLeftAccessory = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pinView.frame.size.height, pinView.frame.size.height)]

UIImageView *temp=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, pinView.frame.size.height- 10, pinView.frame.size.height -10)];
temp.image = image;
temp.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[viewLeftAccessory addView:temp];

pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView=viewLeftAccessory;
```

Hope that will help.

Comment: you forgot this line `viewLeftAccessory=temp;` It worked Thanks Man